# Mysql query to fetch unread response count

Tags: mysql

I have three MYSQL tables

```
Requests -  request_id, request_msg, user_id, request_datetime
Responses - response_id, request_id, response_msg, user_id, response_datetime, readflag
Users-      user_id, user_email, user_name

readflag = 0 or 1
```

I want to fetch the all requests **of a user** where at-least 1 response  is unread for this request, total response count and unread response count for this request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    a.request_id,
    COUNT(*) AS total_response_count,
    COUNT(b.request_id) AS unread_response_count
FROM
    Requests a
LEFT JOIN
    Responses b ON a.request_id = b.request_id AND b.readflag = 0
GROUP BY
    a.request_id
HAVING 
    COUNT(b.request_id) > 0
```

Here, we LEFT JOIN the Responses table on the relationship *and also* where messages are unread (`b.readflag = 0`). This makes all rows with read responses have a NULL value for `b.response_id`. Since `COUNT()` does not factor NULLs into its calculations, we filter only requests that have at least 1 unread response (`HAVING COUNT(b.request_id) > 0`).

Because we LEFT JOINed, all responses are retained, read or unread... just all *read* rows will contain NULL for `b.request_id`. `COUNT(*)` essentially counts on the existence of a row, so that gives us the total count of messages. Then `COUNT(b.request_id)` gives us the count of unread messages as it only factors non-NULL values into its calculation.

Comment: I forgot about HAVING. That's what I was trying to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(`res`.`response_id`) AS `total`, COUNT(`res`.`readflag`='0') AS `unread`
FROM `Requests` AS `req`
LEFT JOIN `Responses` AS `res` ON `req`.`request_id`=`res`.`request_id`
WHERE `unread`>1 AND `req`.`user_id`='[PLACE_USER_ID_HERE]'
```

Comment: I think it will give error  Unknown column 'unread' in 'where clause'

Comment: Hmm, I know I have used something like this before and didn't have an issue with it. Would that depend on the engine?

Comment: My bad, I thought it was in there WHERE clause, but I found out it was in the ORDER BY...